# How can i sum of multiple numbers with each function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to sum of multiple numbers but this is unable to work with each function.

What is tried:-

```js
totalPgCost();
function totalPgCost(){
var totalPgCost = 0;
$('.pgBookingTable tr').find('.pgCost').each(function(){
totalPgCost += $(this).val();
});
$('.totalPgCost').text(totalPgCost);
                    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="pgBookingTable">
<tr><td><span class="pgCost">10000</span></td><tr>
<tr><td><span class="pgCost">5000</span></td><tr>
<tr><td>Total <span class="totalPgCost"></span> /-</td><tr>
</table>
```

Why i'm getting 0?

Answer will appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `text` not `val`. Also the html table is not properly balanced, as there was no closing `tr`. Before adding the convert the string to number

```js
totalPgCost();

function totalPgCost() {
  var totalPgCost = 0;
  $('.pgBookingTable tr').find('.pgCost').each(function() {
    totalPgCost += parseInt($(this).text().trim(), 10);
  });
  $('.totalPgCost').text(totalPgCost);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="pgBookingTable">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="pgCost">10000</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="pgCost">5000</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total <span class="totalPgCost"></span> /-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also avoid `find` if you are sure that only span will inside thar table will have that class

```js
totalPgCost();

function totalPgCost() {
  var totalPgCost = 0;
  $('.pgBookingTable .pgCost').each(function() {
    totalPgCost += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
  });
  $('.totalPgCost').text(totalPgCost);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="pgBookingTable">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="pgCost">10000</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="pgCost">5000</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total <span class="totalPgCost"></span> /-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.text`

```
$('.pgBookingTable tr').find('.pgCost').each(function(){
   totalPgCost += parseInt($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 totalPgCost();
    function totalPgCost(){
    var totalPgCost = 0;
    $('.pgBookingTable tr').find('.pgCost').each(function(){
      totalPgCost += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    $('.totalPgCost').text(totalPgCost);
                        }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <table class="pgBookingTable">
    <tr><td><span class="pgCost">10000</span></td><tr>
    <tr><td><span class="pgCost">5000</span></td><tr>
    <tr><td>Total <span class="totalPgCost"></span> /-</td><tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use `pgCost` for each loop and use `text()` instead of `val()` to get the text within span hope this helps

```js
totalPgCost();
function totalPgCost(){
var totalPgCost = 0;
$('.pgCost').each(function(){
totalPgCost += parseInt($(this).text());
});
$('.totalPgCost').text(totalPgCost);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="pgBookingTable">
<tr><td><span class="pgCost">10000</span></td><tr>
<tr><td><span class="pgCost">5000</span></td><tr>
<tr><td>Total <span class="totalPgCost"></span> /-</td><tr>
</table>
```